# iPhone SDK - CoreAnimation ViewController Transition, Flip From right EDGE

Tags: iphone

I'm currently in the midst of creating an app that requires a very nifty transition.  I would like to be able to;

Invoke my [self presentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and, instead of having CrossDissolve, Generic Flip, or CoverVertical, I would like to employ CoreAnimation to force it to flip from the right edge.  Notice how the normal flip uses the Central Axis? Well, I would like to move that from the Center to the Right Edge, giving the flip a more "In Your Face" effect, similar to the ZuneHD's UI.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
 {
            self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; // we want to overlap the status bar.        
     // when presented, we want to display using a cross dissolve
     self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
 }
    return self;
}
```

Is how I am currently getting the ViewController's transition set.  If possible, I would like the CoreAnimation Right Edge flip to be set here.

If Microsoft can do it, It MUST be possible on the iPhone.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: It may be possible to perform this animation manually, but it's certainly not going to be possible using presentModalViewControllerAnimated:, given that the transition styles are specified by an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the anchorPoint or anchorPointZ, define the axis around which rotations happen. I read some code within the open source "OpenFlow" project that used something similar. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah...that seemed to work on just a general UIView, I need this to apply to a ViewController though...I'm totally stuck on it.

Thanks for your help though! :-)